# AWS & Azure Hybrid Cloud Setup - is this configuration at all possible (Azure Load Balancer -> AWS VM)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, load-balancing, azure-service-fabric

We have all of our cloud assets currently inside Azure, which includes a Service Fabric Cluster containing many applications and services which communicate with Azure VM's through Azure Load Balancers.  The VM's have both public and private IP's, and the Load Balancers' frontend IP configurations point to the private IP's of the VM's.

**What I need to do is move my VM's to AWS**.  Service Fabric **has** to stay put on Azure though. I don't know if this is possible or not.  The Service Fabric services communicate with the Azure VM's through the Load Balancers using the VM's *private* IP addresses.  So the only way I could see achieving this is either:

1. Keep the load balancers in Azure and direct the traffic from them to AWS VM's.
2. Point Azure Service Fabric to AWS load balancers.

I don't know if either of the above are technologically possible.

For #1, if I used Azure's load balancing, I believe the load balancer front-end IP config would have to use the public IP of the AWS VM, right?  Is that not less secure?  If I set it up to go through a VPN (if even possible) is that as secure as using internal private ip's as in the current load balancer config?

For #2, again, not sure if this is technologically achievable - can we even have Service Fabric Services "talk" to AWS load balancers? If so, what is the most secure way to achieve this?

I'm not new to the cloud engineering game, but very new to the idea of using two cloud services as a hybrid solution.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: The main question that I didn't get is "Why you want to keep SF in a Azure if everything else is on AWS?" Maybe the answer for this question will give you better answers than the one above!

Comment: AWS' microservices offering pales in comparison to SFC (in fact many argue that AWS doesn't offer a true microservices cluster at all).  Aside from that, all of our SFC applications were built in .NET over the course of a year-and-a-half.  The amount of time and resources it would take to migrate that over to AWS would far exceed that of simply "moving the cluster over to AWS."  Also, I only mentioned SFC and the VMs b/c they are what's relevant to the question.  Those components make up about 20% of our entire Azure back-end.  So we're still deeply entrenched in Azure even if we did move SFC.

Comment: Please see the answer I've added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know creating multiregion / multi-datacenter cluster in Service Fabric is possible.

Here are the [brief](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions#can-i-create-a-cluster-that-spans-multiple-azure-regions-or-my-own-datacenters) list of requirements to have initial mindset about how this would work and here is a [sample](https://github.com/ChackDan/Service-Fabric/tree/master/ARM%20Templates/Multi%20Region%20Spanning%20Sample) **not approved by Microsoft** with cross region Service Fabric cluster configuration (I know this are different regions in Azure not different cloud provider but this sample can be of use to see how some of the things are configured).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oleg, very interesting to see that this exact subject is being worked on.  I will dive deep into your links today!  Thank you for this information!

Comment: Oleg, would you be willing to take continued discussion about this to private chat?  I have a couple additional questions for you.

Comment: @Stpete111 I am not sure about the chat but you can email me and I would try to help you if possible.

Comment: That would be great. Where can I find your email address?

Comment: @Stpete111 you can find it in my profile on GitHub (there is a link in the StackOverflow profile). Sorry for making it so hard.

Comment: No problem Oleg, I understand not posting it here.  Thanks, I'll reach out soon!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details provided in the comments of you own question:

SF is cloud agnostic, you could deploy your entire cluster without any dependencies on Azure at all. 
The cluster you see in your azure portal is just an Azure Resource Screen used to describe the details of your cluster.

Your are better of creating the entire cluster in AWS, than doing the requested approach, because at the end, the only thing left in azure would be this Azure Resource Screen.

Extending the Oleg answer, *"creating multiregion / multi-datacenter cluster in Service Fabric is possible."* I would add, that is also possible to create an azure agnostic cluster where you can host on AWS, Google Cloud or On Premises.

The only details that is not well clear, is that any other option not hosted in azure requires an extra level of management, because you have to play around with the resources(VM, Load Balancers, AutoScaling, OS Updates, and so on) to keep the cluster updated and running.

Also, multi-region and multi-zone cluster were something left aside for a long time in the SF roadmap because it is something very complex to do and this is why they avoid recommend, but is possible.

If you want to go for AWS approach, I guide you to this tutorial: [Create AWS infrastructure to host a Service Fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-standalone-create-infrastructure)

This is the first of a 4 part tutorial with guidance on how you can Setup a SF Cluster on AWS infrastructure.

Regarding the other resources hosted on Azure, You could still access then from AWS without any problems.

Comment: Great info, Diego!  It's very interesting to see that it's possible to create an SFC on AWS.  This is not what we're trying to accomplish, but it's good to know it exists as an alternative approach.  Thanks for taking the time to point me to the link and info.